# Undefined variable: tags in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

this is my first app ever.
It is always happening in every single method I do.

My TagController:

```
 public function destroy($id)
{
    $tag = Tag::find($id);
    $tag->posts()->detach();

    $tag->delete();

    return redirect()->route('tags.index');
}
```

In my PostController:

```
public function delete(Post $post)
{
    $post->delete();
    $post->tags()->detach();
    return redirect()->route('admin.post.index');
}
```

In My index view:

```
<a class="btn red" method="DELETE" href="{{route('tag.delete',$tag->id) }}">Deletar</a>
```

Im making a tag system for a newsboard where people are going to upload news. Can someone help me? Thank you already!

Comment: in my PostController `$post->tags()->detach();
        $post->delete();` Try to detatch first

Comment: Error: Undefined variable: tags.

In my index tags:

</tr>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($tags as $tag): ?>
                    <div class="container">
                    <tr>
 
                        <td> <?php echo e($tag->id); ?> </td>
                        <td> <?php echo e($tag->name); ?> </td>

Comment: Have you defined tag relationship in post model ?

Comment: yes! in my post model: public function tags() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');

    }

Comment: `$this->belongsToMany('App\Tag','tag_id');` add tag_id as second argument.

Comment: Happening the same error :(

Comment: can you also show us the TagController index() method? The Error you describe seems to be related to that

Comment: yes! here it is:

public function index()
    {
        $tags = Tag::all();
        return view('tags.index')->withTags($tags);
    }

Comment: So this is happening only after you delete a tag, and TagController@destroy redirects you to tags index? Or it is happening every time you try to access tags index?

Comment: Only when i click in the delete button on tags.index